# How do to get Selenium in Python to use a drop-down calender?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, calendar

Hey guys so i am trying to build a small program that using Selenium to go to the site: http://www.booking.com/ in which the user puts in the Destination, checkin/checkout date. But i dont know exactly how to use Selenium to work a calendar. Have a look at my code below from what i have tried out of logic. Someone please help if you understand the problem and can solve it. Thank you!

I have tried coding what's below for the site booking.com: Check-In section:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time

browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get('http://www.booking.com')

wait = WebDriverWait(browser, 2)
D_H_Name = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, "ss")))
D_H_Name.click()
D_H_Name.clear()
print("Enter Destination/Hotel Name:")
D_H_Name.send_keys(input())

time.sleep(3)
D_H_Name.send_keys(Keys.DOWN)

time.sleep(1)
D_H_Name.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)

CheckIn_date = browser.find_element_by_css_selector("div.class ")

#wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.sb-calendar__col")))
#print("Enter CheckIn Date:")
#CheckIn_date.send_keys(input())


CheckIn_date.send_keys(input())
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use the `Select` functionality:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
selectDay = Select(driver.find_element_by_name('checkin_monthday'))
selectDay.select_by_visible_text("20")

selectMonth = Select(driver.find_element_by_name('checkin_year_month'))
selectMonth.select_by_visible_text("April 2016")
```

`Select` can work off of index, text, or option value:

```
select.select_by_index(index)
select.select_by_visible_text("text")
select.select_by_value(value)
```

Comment: Hey, for booking.com the calendar can change a few times every time you reload the page. I don't know why it does, but they way you should it to me works sometimes if the page has a separate drop down menu for the day, month, and year. But otherwise it does not. Do you think there might be another way for that it can work for both?

Answer (score 0):

```html
HI This is kumar.try the following apporach

 WebDriver driver = new firefoxDriver();
 driver.get("http://www.booking.com/");
  driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@class='sb-dates__calendar-button b-datepicker b-sprite calendar_icon']")).clcik();
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@class='c2-day-inner'](text()='20')")).clcik();
```